# Wordpress Count authors post , If count is 2 then show pop up message

Tags: wordpress

Am looking to add a code in the function.php in the theme directory rather then  downloading a plugin as i have so many already i just want to add a code instead.

when a logged in author visits www.example.com/newpost   then Count logged in authors post , If count is 2 then show pop up message you have reached your post limit ( ok button ) redirects to homepage.

This is so far i have dug up from google.

```
<p><?php the_author(); ?> has blogged <?php the_author_posts(); ?> 
posts</p>
```

now am not sure if am doing this right but il give it a try 
author tries to visit this page 
www.example.com/newpost

```
if the_author_posts() == "2" { 
"error you have reached your limits"
{else}
continue posting because it has not reached 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several things at play here.

1. The url you provided - is that an *admin dashboard* page you are trying to reference? Or is that a *front-end* page?  If it's an admin dashboard page (to add a new post) then this is a much different thing to do.
2. You are using [the_author_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_posts/) - that function **displays** the number of posts.  For a comparison like what you want, you need to use [get_the_author_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_posts/).
3. If you want to add this in the theme functions file, you can do that - but you've got to either determine the hook you need to hook into, or else you need to modify a template (depends on your answer to #1 above).

In functions, you could do something like this:

```
function is_within_limit() {
    if (get_the_author_posts() < 2) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        echo 'You have already posted your maximum number of posts.';
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

But then the question is - where / how do you hook this?  Answer question #1 above (if this is in admin, or a front-end page), and I can provide that piece to this solution.

Comment: i want to assign this code only for regular users not admin ,  this code should take affect for all other users but not admin , by the way this code is giving me white page sir.     your code is find looks great just need to resolve why its giving white page    this  url www.example.com/newpost   is only on front end , its a classified site so if users visit www.example.com/newpost  then it should check if that user has past its post limits

Comment: In your wp-config file, set WP_DEBUG to true.  White pages are not helpful for troubleshooting, and that will cause it to show errors.  I have updated my answer - I had one too many closing parentheses.  PLEASE answer question #1 - what is the actual URL you will use this on? Without that, I cannot help!

Comment: white page resolved , am not getting any messages its not detecting the post count ?

Comment: OK, so that page is front-end.  Can you modify the theme template? How is the "create new post" exposed on the front-end?  I can help you if I understand how they create the new post through the front end.  Is it a Gravity Form?  Is that form embedded in the content of that page?